# want to show validation error on handlechange using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React 16, Please find the below code which I am using for Validation using hooks. I have used a reusable Select box and on the value of the option, I am showing an input box.
Validation rules: if the select box is empty on click of submit i want to show error and hide it when I select a value then if the input box is empty want to show error and hide when we give valid input.
Problem : When error message appears for select box and after selecting the value when input box appears it shows the error for that too so it's like the first look of input box is with the validation error. I want to show it when user clicks submit button and onchange after valid entry it should go away.

Really appreciate the help!

```
  const Step3 = (props) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({});
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
    const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(validate);
    useEffect(() => { if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) { } }, [errors]);

    const onChange = (event) => { 
        event.persist && event.persist(); 
        setIsSubmitting(false);
        const newValues = {...values,[event.target.name]:event.target.value};
        isSent && setErrors(validate(newValues));
        setValues(values => newValues);
     };
    const handleSubmit = (event) => { 
        if (event) event.preventDefault(); 
        setErrors(validate(values)); 
        setIsSubmitting(true); 
        setIsSent(true);
    };
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
          <Select
            name="abc"
            label="ABC"
            options={options}
            onChange={onChange}
            
        />
          {errors.abc && (<p className="help is-danger">{errors.abc}</p>)}
          
            {values.abc=='Apple' && <input name="xyz" value={values.xyz||'' onChange={onChange}}/>
                {errors.xyz && (<p className="help is-danger">{errors.xyz}</p> )}
            }
            
          <Button type={submit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
};

function validate(values) {
     let errors = {}
     if (!values.abc)
     { errors.abc= ' required'; }
     if (!values.xyz) {
     errors.xyz= 'required'; 
     }
     return errors;
 };
```

Comment: Can you post code here in a minimal..

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I have added the code...Thanks, Nikhil  and Adir

Comment: Please let me know of a solution .... input box validation error also appears when drop down validation shows up on click of submit button. I want to show input box validation error only if user forgets to give value and clicks submit or when invalid data is given onchange should show and hide when valid option is given.

Answer (score 0):

```
useForm({ mode: 'onChange' })
```

Doc:
https://react-hook-form.com/api#useForm

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-defaultvalues-v6-forked-s9buh?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks @Sheldon....Please find my updated code...the issue is as soon as I select the value in drop down the dropdown validation goes away but when input box appears , it shows with the validation error as the submit button was already clicked for the drop down box. Looking forward for your response.